# How do I open files in the most recently active Atom editor window instead of the Atom window I first opened?

Tags: linux, atom-editor, archlinux

Using Atom editor on Linux, I can't seem to find any option for opening files (using my file manager) in the most recent Atom window that was active. Instead, it always opens in the very first Atom window that was created.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option for this:

`-a, --add    Open path as a new project in last used window.  [boolean]`

…but anyway, it does not work as expected. However, I`ve found a workaround.

This code is located somewhere around line 862 of `src/main-process/atom-application.js`:

```
    if (existingWindow == null) {
      if (currentWindow = window != null ? window : this.lastFocusedWindow) {
        if (addToLastWindow || currentWindow.devMode === devMode && (stats.every(function(stat) {
          return typeof stat.isFile === "function" ? stat.isFile() : void 0;
        }) || stats.some(function(stat) {
          return (typeof stat.isDirectory === "function" ? stat.isDirectory() : void 0) && !currentWindow.hasProjectPath();
        }))) {
          existingWindow = currentWindow;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment out the first line and its former closing bracket:

```
//    if (existingWindow == null) {
      if (currentWindow = window != null ? window : this.lastFocusedWindow) {
        if (addToLastWindow || currentWindow.devMode === devMode && (stats.every(function(stat) {
          return typeof stat.isFile === "function" ? stat.isFile() : void 0;
        }) || stats.some(function(stat) {
          return (typeof stat.isDirectory === "function" ? stat.isDirectory() : void 0) && !currentWindow.hasProjectPath();
        }))) {
          existingWindow = currentWindow;
        }
      }
//    }
```

…aaaand voilà!

It`s a *hackable* text editor, after all ^_^

Comment: This would have to be redone after every atom update unfortunately.

Comment: @Raj, then wouldn`t it be better to raise an issue on [atom Github page](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues)? The current behaviour is apparently not the expected one.

Comment: And BTW, having read the code some more, I\`m quite sure that my correction is legitimate, because all it does is inverting priorities for `this.windowForPaths` and `this.lastFocusedWindow`.

Comment: You're saying I should create a pull request with your exact change because it's mistakenly inverting priorities for `this.windowForPaths` and `this.lastFocusedWindow`?

Comment: I guess I better create it myself. I don\`t like it when other people take blame for my mistakes.

Comment: Those devs didn't even respond to your pull request. I can't believe other people haven't complained about this issue.